# Type conversion issue with Apache Camel and Spring

Tags: java, spring, types, apache-camel

I'm trying to externalize my Camel Spring (Camel 2.20.2; Spring 4.3.14) configuration into an `application.properties` property file. This property file has the following content:

```
net.sender1.port = 47000
net.sender1.address = 127.255.255.255
```

The `application.properties` file resides within `src/main/resources` and is copied to the target jar by the maven-shade-plugin.

My Camel context looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:camel="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
  <bean id="udpSender1" class="com.foo.MyUDPSender">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${net.sender1.address}" />
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Integer" value="${net.sender1.port}" />
  </bean>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    ...
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

When I start the application, I get the following error:

```
WARN | 2018-02-23 09:50:25,324 | [main]  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.refresh  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'udpSender1' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Integer]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${net.sender1.port}"
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'udpSender1' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Integer]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${net.sender1.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:222)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at com.foo.Server.main(Server.java:19)
```

It seems that the `address` property is parsed correctly, because it's a String. Which means that the application can find the properties-file.

Is there any way to explicitly define a type in the properties or in the spring xml?

Comment: Hello could you pls try to reformat the property file without spaces. E.g net.sender1.port=47000
net.sender1.address=127.255.255.255

Comment: Thanks Themis, but spaces are not the issue, I've tried that at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your properties-file is, in fact, not found by your application. It is trying to convert the String literal "${net.sender1.port}" to an Integer, which is why you get a NumberFormatException.

You need to specify a `PropertyPlaceholder` in order to read your external properties-file.

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</bean>
```

If you add the above to your application it should at least be able to read the actual properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also follow construction

```
<beans ...
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="...
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
         ">
  <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties"/>
  <util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:application.properties"/>

</beans>
```